# Quartz trigger doesn't fire when using JobStoreTX

Tags: quartz-scheduler, websphere-liberty, quartz

I am configuring Quartz for my application under IBM Liberty Profile. When I used the default RAMJobStore. The trigger was fired and the scheduled job ran. Here are the codes:

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzBatchJobs.class).build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startNow().build();
try {
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

However, when I switched to jdbcjobstore JobStoreTX and ran the application, all the quartz tables were updated but the trigger itself wasn't fired and the job didn't run. Here is my quartz.properties:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=quartzRepo
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzRepo.jndiURL=jdbc/quartzRepo
```

Here is the server.xml of Liberty Profile for data source.

```
<dataSource id="quartzRepo" jndiName="jdbc/quartzRepo" type="javax.sql.XADataSource" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED">
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2Jcc4Lib" />
<properties.db2.jcc currentSchema="qrtz" databaseName="localdb2" password="${jdbc.quartzRepo.password}" portNumber="50000" serverName="localhost" user="${jdbc.quartzRepo.user}" driverType="4" />
</dataSource>
```

Could you guys please give me some suggestions on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your data source configuration looks pretty standard, and if you've said the tables were successfully created with it, that is further evidence of it being correct.  Have you checked the server logs for the presence of any exceptions/errors that might indicate problems quartz is running into when it tries to schedule/run jobs?

Comment: Thank you njr. Should I use JobStoreTX or JobStoreCMT given that my application runs under liberty?

Comment: You can use either in Liberty.  You will need to decide whether you want to perform operations on your Quartz jobs in a JTA transaction (JobStoreCMT) or not.